# Animate video UIView to go full screen like YouTube App

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

I have a view controller that has a `UIView` that I call `playerView`. In `playerView`, I use an `AVLayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` to show the user a video. Image the Youtube app when you first click on any video.

How do I manipulate the frame of this `playerView` so that it can take up the entire screen. (Go full screen)

This is the current frame:

```
 //16 x 9 is the aspect ratio of all HD videos
 let height = view.frame.width * 9 / 16
 let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)    
 playerView.frame = videoPlayerFrame
```

I was testing around in the YouTube app and their app only supports Portrait orientation (just like mine) due to how the animation of a video going full screen looks. How can I do this at the the tap of a button and even further when the user holds the device horizontally?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

   self.playerView.frame = ?

}, completion: nil)
```

Edit: Tried this but it doesn't really work how I want it... it doesn't take up the whole screen

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

   self.playerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.height, height: self.view.frame.width)
   self.playerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))

}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You should not animate the frame. Animate the transform and you'll be Ok

Comment: @Mannopson Thanks for the advice! Can you show some sample code?

Comment: I meant transform's scales and not frame.

Comment: @Mannopson Do you mind posting some code? I'm having trouble deciphering your message

Comment: I'll give you an idea but not now. Ok?

Comment: @Mannopson Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

I create a global variable called `isExpanded` that will be set to true when we're in full screen mode. Also, I create a CGPoint variable called `videoPlayerViewCenter` so I can save the center before going full screen so I can set it again when going back to small screen.

This is the code that gets called when the user wants to go full screen

```
func fullScreenTapped(sender: vVideoPlayer) {

        if !isExpanded {
            //Expand the video
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.videoPlayerViewCenter = self.videoPlayerView.center

                self.videoPlayerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.height, height: self.view.frame.width)
                self.videoPlayerView.center = self.view.center
                self.videoPlayerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
                self.videoPlayerView.layoutSubviews()

            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            //Shrink the video again

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                //16 x 9 is the aspect ratio of all HD videos

                self.videoPlayerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                self.videoPlayerView.center = self.videoPlayerViewCenter

                let height = self.view.frame.width * 9 / 16
                let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: height)
                self.videoPlayerView.frame = videoPlayerFrame

                self.videoPlayerView.layoutSubviews()

            }, completion: nil)
        }

        isExpanded = !isExpanded
    }
```

To expand the video, I save the center in my global CGPoint variable and then set the frame. Then, I set the center and do a 90 degree turn using `CGAffineTransform`.

To shrink the video again, I basically set the settings to how they were before. (The order in which things are done is very important)

Another thing that's also very important is to override your `layoutSubviews` method in your videoPlayerView to be like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.playerLayer?.frame = self.bounds
    }
```

This will make it so your `playerLayer` adjusts its frame as the view is getting bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I know is too late but maybe someone else can find this code helpful.

I use to use Auto layout constraints in my views so animating must have a different approach.

```
func setMapFullScreen(_ fullscreen: Bool) {

    if fullscreen {
        // Set the full screen constraints
        self.setFullScreenLayoutConstraints()

        // Hide the navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    } else {
        // Set small screen constraints
        self.setSmallScreenLayoutConstraints()

        // Show the navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    // Animate to full screen
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (finished) in
        // ...
    }
```

In my case a have I [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview) and I want to tap on it in order to see the map fullscreen (and back).
This is the function that toogle the state.

As you can see, in the `UIView.animate` call, I animate only the `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

I also hide the navigation bar cause I have one ☺

Here my `setSmallScreenLayoutConstraints` and `setFullScreenLayoutConstraints` functions using [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io/) framework

```
func setSmallScreenLayoutConstraints() {
    self.mapView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(self.mapLabel.snp.bottom).offset(8)
        make.left.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
        make.right.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
        make.height.equalTo(150)
    }
}

func setFullScreenLayoutConstraints() {
    self.mapView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
        make.left.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
        make.right.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view).offset(0)
    }
}
```

This is the result

### [image: Map animation]

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

As I said it is not an answer for your question. It is an idea and hope it helps you:

```
 var rectangleView:UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Tap Gesture Recognizer for growing the rectangleView
    let tapForward = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapForward(tap:)))
    tapForward.numberOfTapsRequired = 1


    // Configure the rectangleView
    self.rectangleView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    self.rectangleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.65, y: 0.25)
    self.rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.rectangleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapForward)
    self.view.addSubview(rectangleView)
}
```

And this going to be our `tapForward(tap:)` function:

```
func tapForward(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.rectangleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }) { (completed:Bool) in
        // Completion block
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mannopson. Can you explain what this does?

Comment: So we have created a custom `UIView` with the smaller scales. And it is grows to full screen mode whenever it's tapped

Comment: this doesn't help. You're simply setting a view to a full size .. scaling it down... then setting it back to it's original size. If you look at the animation that youtube does, the view flips and takes up the entire landscape area. It I would follow your way of doing it, I would have to first set the view to take up the whole size then somehow figure out a way to scale it down to be shown as the original youtube video is seen.. small at the top. No idea how to go even go about it....